# How close can a wormhole appear next to a star so that it doesn't affect it?

Tags: space, travel, wormholes

In context, I need to transport a package that has gotten very close to the sun, and I've chosen to use a wormhole. 
What I need to know is if there is a certain distance that needs to be considered so that the wormhole doesn't effect the star or any planets within that solar system.

Comment: You should also specify what's on the other end. If the wormhole leads to a very short distance over the event horizon of a supermassive black hole you can bet it will affect you no matter where it is. If it leads to intragalactic empty space it likely won't have much of an effect.

Comment: If you connect two places that have similar conditions then the effects are minimal. With that said, there would always be some effect... so "it doesn't affect it" can't really be met, we need to know how small of an effect is good enough.

Comment: Google for “effect vs affect”. I edited the title.

Comment: Why are people referring to wormholes as if they are actual, real phenomenon? Is there some reference to them which gives their apparent structure and behavior? Or are they thought to be Einstein–Rosen bridges?

Answer (score 1):

No, a generic “smart” sci-fi wormhole does not have a minimum distance to a star. Readers won’t squak if you do that, assuming you didn’t already establish rules to the contrary within your story.

Comment: Squak? As in "Readers won’t squak" methinks I should add this to my list of interesting typos.

Comment: Not so much a typo as in it’s not obvious how an onomatopoeic word gets its spelling standardized.  My bird in particular does not have a “W” in his rendition of the sound, at least not at the right end. I think it’s like /skwɔːk/.  Ah, I see the spelling comes from *squall* and *hawk*.  I guess it could just as easily have been taken from *walk* which would make it “squalk”.  Which now that I see it, I recall having actually seen.

Comment: Not everyday I have to contemplate onomatopoeic standardization. While "comes from squall and hawk" suggests an accipitrine bird that hunt during storms. What am I saying? Time to quit while I'm ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is on the other side of the wormhole. Wormholes act as if two places are next to each other, so if there is a sizable object nearby to the exit, it would cause trouble. But if it is far from anything, not much would happen. Also you might want to keep the duration of the wormhole as brief as possible.

For the best result, you can open a wormhole between the Earth and the Jupiter. On the other side, it should reside somewhere similar.